# Using multiple arrays with one UICollectionView showing cells at wrong position with empty space before them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I'm using a single collectionView which shows a view with label inside it horizontally. With a click of some buttons I'm changing the data that is passed into the collectionView and reloading it. It seems fine until we have data with less count that previous data. For example, if data count = 3 and I reload and now data count = 2, the properties of previous cells are retained and when data count == 4 and after reloading data count == 1, the cell is shown at right side of collection view with empty space before it, just like 3 earlier cells from previous data count, however shouldn't whole collectionView should be updated after reloading data? or it just reloads data? and if data size is 1, it will just show data at last cell created previously for data size = 4, ie. 4 cells for previous data? I mean data reloading keeps 4 cells and shows new data at 4th cell with 3 empty cells before it? Here is all of my code so you can understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
func updateCollectionView(index: Int) {
        if index == 1 {
            collectionViewArray = array1
        }
        else if index == 2 {
            collectionViewArray = array2
        }
        else if index == 3 {
            collectionViewArray = array3
        }
        else if index == 4 {
            collectionViewArray = array4
        }
        else if index == 5 {
            collectionViewArray = array5
        }
        else if index == 6 {
            collectionViewArray = array6
        }
        else if index == 7 {
            collectionViewArray = array7
        }
        else {
            collectionViewArray = array8
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here above "index" comes from buttons, pressing one button will send index = 1, another will send index = 2 and so on as input for above function.

Here below is collectionView datasource:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return collectionViewArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCategoriesCollectionViewCell
                        
            let data = collectionViewArray[indexPath.row]
            
            cell.label.text = data

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            }
            
            return cell

    }
```

These are my arrays:

```
var array1 = ["1", "2"]
var array2 = ["6", "8"]
var array3 = ["5", "90", "78"]
var array4 = ["69", "70", "788", "89889"]
var array5 = ["45", "66", "48"]
var array6 = ["15", "44"]
var array7 = ["00", "abc", "56", "67"]
var array8 = ["0"]
```

The above code results in required functionality with view background colour set as blue for 1st item however when I return array 4, there is blue colour for item 3, ie.. indexPath == 2. And finally for array 8, the cell has empty space before it and is positioned too far right. for array  7, all views have blue colour instead of just item1.

Comment: Cells are reused.  While you set the background color to blue if the index is 0, you don't set the background color if the index *isn't* 0.  When a cell is reused, you will get whatever background color it had previously.  You need an `else` clause. Your `cellForItemAt` code should always explicitly set all your required properties of your cell.  You cannot assume any existing state

Comment: @Paulw11 I had that. I removed it before posting this question. It didnt do anything. Even just now I added it back and still no change. It still shows blue colour for all cells sometimes for arrays with 4 items & still blank space for array with one item

Comment: Aside from not setting the background colour I can't see anything wrong with your code. From your description it sounds like your constraints for your collection view aren't correct

Comment: @Paulw11 I just changed flow from vertical to horizontal as that's what I needed. Still issue exists. I even added prepareForReuse in cell class to reset background colour of view. Still not working and weirdly for array with 1 item, cell won't even show when flow = horizontal

Comment: Definitely sounds like a constraints problem. Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I'm using storyboard. I did make some changes in storyboard and now the layout issue is fixed. Now only background colour for view issue remains. Still other cells at some times shows colour instead of only the cell at indexPath = 0